# Is there a way to add columns to dataframe that is in the form of function

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to add columns to dataframe that is in the form of function

```
dfs <- function(){iris}
d <- nrow(dfs())
dfs()$new <- seq_len(d)
Error in dfs()$new <- seq_len(d) : invalid (NULL) left side of assignment
```

Expected output

```
head(dfs())
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   1
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   3
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   4
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa   5
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   6
```

Comment: Well, if you want to add a column, presumably you want to assign this back to *something*. Are you expecting to be able add the column, and then call `dfs()` later and have it still be there? I think the answer is "no". You'd have to reassign a new function to overwrite the old one.

Answer (score 3):

There is no object created in the global env.  In that case, we can use `transform`

```
transform(dfs(), new = seq_len(d))
```

Or use

```
 `[<-`(dfs(), "new", value =  seq_len(d))
```

---

If we want to use `$`, create an object

```
tmp <- dfs()
tmp$new <- seq_len(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Adam for the suggestions. We can use `1:n()` to have more cleaner code.

```r
library(dplyr)

dfs <- function() {
  iris
}

dfs() %>%
  {
    mutate(., new = 1:nrow(.))
  } %>%
  head()
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   1
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   2
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   3
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   4
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa   5
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   6

dfs() %>%
  mutate(new = 1:n()) %>%
  head()
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   1
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   2
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   3
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   4
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa   5
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   6

dfs() %>%
  mutate(new = 1:nrow(cur_data())) %>%
  head()
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species new
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   1
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   2
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa   3
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa   4
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa   5
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa   6
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Does `dfs() %>% mutate(new = 1:n())` not just work on its own? Why the extra?

Comment: @Adam Good point! It results in much cleaner code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `add_column` function from `tibble` package:

```
library(tibble)               
mtcars %>% 
  add_column(my_new_column = 1:32,
             .after = "cyl")
```